# If-then constraints with binary variables in Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, binary-programming

How can the constraint: if $x_1=1$ then $x_2+x_3\geq 1$ be written in linear programming if the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are binary?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a derivation via conjunctive normal form:
\begin{equation}
x_1 \implies (x_2 \lor x_3) \\
\neg x_1 \lor (x_2 \lor x_3) \\
(1 - x_1) + x_2 + x_3 \ge 1 \\
x_1 \le x_2 + x_3 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

$-x1 + x2 + x3 \geq 0 $

should be sufficient.